# running Spring Boot for REST

Tags: spring, spring-boot, datasource

I created a spring boot application with Rest Controller and Oracle on my local system, thru IDE its running fine, the mvn build was fine package was also good but if I run it as executable jar I am getting the below error. I have application.properties in which I have provided all spring.datasource, but here I am getting error. Please advise.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1056) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1028) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sumit.location.AppBootConfig.main(AppBootConfig.java:22) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [location.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [location.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [location.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [location.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]


Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
```

here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.sumit.location</groupId>
<artifactId>location</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>location Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId> <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version> 
        </dependency> -->
    <!-- added the below oracle jdbc dependency to get the ojdbc7 jar into 
        classpath -->
    <!-- the oracle jars are not publically hosted in maven repo so we have 
        to download it seperatly and install it to maven -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0.1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/lib/ojdbc7.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>



</dependencies>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>location</finalName>
</build>
```

I am trying out Spring boot and trying to run it as a excutable jar.

Comment: =>  Cannot load driver class: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Comment: so how can I load it? its running fine in IDE.

Comment: I googled and found it to store the ojdbc jar in that path. in addition, if I am running my queries without packing it into jar and straight through IDE its not throwing me the same error.

Comment: I believe you should change `<scope>system</scope>` to  `<scope>runtime</scope>` (or `<scope>compile</scope>`)

Comment: if I put it as runtime/compile scope its asking me to omit the <systemPath> but if I remove the system path its giving error that 
`Missing artifact com.oracle:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0.1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` isn't found at runtime, because ojdbc7.jar is included with the `system` scope, which is just like `provided` in terms of visibility. It works in Eclipse because Eclipse doesn't botter with the scopes and just includes everything at runtime.

You need the dependency to be either `compile` or `runtime` at least. I believe it cannot be done with a *file dependency*.

## Solution 1 - Define a local repository

Define a maven repository to point to your jar location:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>project-local-repo</id>
    <url>file://${project.basedir}/src/lib/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Move/rename your library to `${project.basedir}/src/lib/com/oracle/ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar`

And then include it normally:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

## Solution 2 - install the library into your .m2

Use the following command to install jar into your .m2 repository:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<jarfilePath> \
    -DgroupId=<groupId> \
    -DartifactId=<artifactId> \
    -Dversion=<version> \
    -Dpackaging=<packaging> \
    -DlocalRepositoryPath=<repoPath>
```

I think the following should do the job:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=..../src/lib/ojdbc7.jar \
    -DgroupId=com.oracle \
    -DartifactId=ojdbc7 \
    -Dversion=12.1.0.1 \
    -Dpackaging=jar
```

And then declare a normal dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I will Try this. Thank you

Comment: it worked. I think I didn't had the jar installed properly. I installed it again and changed as you said. Thank you.