# add jar to the maven local repository before build

Tags: java, maven

i have third part jar file which doesn't exist remotely the file located inside the project directory , i want to add this jar into the local repository when i execute mvn install, my current code for doing that

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-file</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <groupId>myJar1.0</groupId>
                <artifactId>myJar1.0</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <packaging>jar</packaging>
                <file>myJar1.0.jar</file>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: maybe better to take a different approach, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path/2230464#2230464

Comment: Do you got some error? Please report the command line too.

Comment: Best is to start using a repository manager and install that JAR there and use afterwards as a usual dependency..That's it...

Comment: @Redlab this solution will require every developer to run 'install-file' command at their machines, what i want is to fix this problem entirely without any intervention from any developer

Comment: @Mario Santini, no errors

Comment: @khmarbaise what i want is to fix this problem entirely without any intervention from any developer, what you suggested will requires every developer to add the jar into the local repo

Comment: Perhaps clarify your real question in the question also. It is not fully clear what you want

Comment: If you do not want any intervention you can do it like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2229775/299787

Comment: @MeladEzzat You missed my point. Using a repository manager will solve that for all developers and needed only a single task to solve the problem for all of them...

Comment: @ khmarbaise ok i missed your point because i don't know how to use repository manager for now, but i will do more studies about it ,Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a repository manager is the best solution. However, here's a solution that can be setup entirely through `pom.xml` configuration (without developer interventions):

## Add a local repository pointing to your jar location:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>project-local-repo</id>
    <url>file://${project.basedir}/src/lib/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Move/rename your library to ${project.basedir}/src/lib/some-group-name/myJar-1.0.jar

## And then you can include the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>some-group-name</groupId>
    <artifactId>myJar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The dependency will be picked up at every build.
I wrote a similar answer here: [running Spring Boot for REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41661895/running-spring-boot-for-rest)

Comment: This is the best answer I've seen for this issue. It doesn't require any additional actions, thank  you.

Comment: Move/rename your library to ${project.basedir}/src/lib/some/group/name/myJar/1.0/myJar-1.0.jar

Answer (score 6):

Actually its not so complicated.

There are 2 cases that you need to issue Maven’s command to include a jar into the Maven local repository manually.

- The jar you want to use doesn’t exist in the Maven center repository.
- You created a custom jar, and need to use for another Maven project.

**Steps:**

### 1. **mvn install**:

put your jar somewhere, lets assume its under `c:\`:

```
 mvn install:install-file -Dfile=c:\myJar{version}.jar 
 -DgroupId=YOUR_GROUP -DartifactId=myJar -Dversion={version} -Dpackaging=jar
```

Now, the "myJar" jar is copied to your Maven local repository.

### 2. **pom.xml**:

After installed, just declares the `myJar` coordinate in pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>YOUR_GROUP</groupId>
     <artifactId>myJar</artifactId>
     <version>{version}</version>
</dependency>
```

### 3. **Done**

Build it, now the **"myJar"** jar is able to retrieve from your Maven local repository.

---

NOTE: this example was based on the [another example](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/) which I encourage you to read for further information.